# Multiple Jasperserver instances

Tags: multiple-instances, jasperserver

Need some help...

I have jasperserver 4.1 installed on my ubuntu. It runs via bundled tomcat server on 8080 port.
I've installed jasperserver 4.5 on the same host in different folder, and want them to run together. Second tomcat instance is listening on 8081 port.

The problem is when I log in (with the same credentials) via jasperserver web-interface at **localhost:8080/jasperserver** i am throwed out at **localhost:8081/jasperserver** and vice versa.

Repositories are different for sure.
Maybe jasperserver use some single auth mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to sessions/cookie mechanism, because if i open them (localhost:8080/jasperserver, localhost:8081/jasperserver) in different browsers everything works ok.